# Appending dynamically generated lists to a new list

Tags: list, dynamic, prolog

I am trying to add a list into an already created list. `program(Route, FinalRoute).` The `Route` variable is a list which is changed multiple times during the execution of the program, however, there is a stage when `Route` needs to be appended to `FinalRoute`.

This process can take place several times, however I am not sure how can I achieve this.

The following is the related (important/required) code which might explain what I am doing right now:

```
path(_, _, Route, FinalRoute, []):-
    %% code to add Route to FinalRoute

path(Source, Dest, Route, FinalRoute, Conditions):-
    [Cond|Rest] = Conditions,
    get_info(Source, Dest, Path, NewDest),
    path(Dest, NewDest, [Path|Route], FinalRoute, Rest).
```

The path predicate is not called once but multiple times, hence a simple `Route = FinalRoute` will not suffice.

So `Route` can be `[1, 2, 3]` then `FinalRoute` should be `[[1, 2, 3]]`.

When `Route` is `[4, 5, 6]` then `FinalRoute` should be `[[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3]]`, etc.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (pure) Prolog we can't assign to a variable. At any point, it's either *free* or *bound*.

Then I can't answer meaningfully to your question. The solution depends on the context where path/5 get called. Some alternatives are:

- assert(route(Route)), and collect them all when your program is done.
- use findall(FinalRoute, path(Source, Dest, Route, FinalRoute, Conditions), AllRoutes)
- add an accumulator, playing a role similar to current Route/FinalRoute pair

*edit* an accumulator is easy to add, but it will be useful only if you actually call `path` without backtracking, thus  (say, in 'forward' mode).

```
path(_, _, Route, RoutesSoFar, [Route|RoutesSoFar], []).
path(Source, Dest, Route, SoFar, AllRoutes, Conditions):-
    [Cond|Rest] = Conditions,
    get_info(Source, Dest, Path, NewDest),
    path(Dest, NewDest, [Path|Route], SoFar, AllRoutes, Rest).
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on the accumulator part. Also, the `findall/3` doesn't help as initially i need to add all `Routes` to `FinalRoute`, but the FinalRoute cannot be appended with the Routes again and again.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however, my program strongly requires backtracking.

Comment: Yes, I think you should try to adapt your program flow to findall, or assert and then collect all.

Comment: `findall` does not play along well either, as for the same example as you provided `AllRoutes` cannot be updated multiple times. Hence, leading to the same problem.